# Xcode expand/collapse braces/brackets {} side bar missing

Tags: xcode, code-folding

The side bar, next to the code line numbers, that allows expansion/collapsing of brace/brackets {} is no longer showing in Xcode. I am trying to figure out how to get it back.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to Xcode Preferences/Text Editing and check the "Code Folding Ribbon" box.

EDIT: As of Version 9.0.1 (9A1004), this feature has been removed from Xcode 9. I am looking for a new editor because I use this feature so much, and I cannot believe they actually removed it in Xcode 9.

Answer (score 12):

Code folding is working now, in Xcode 9 Beta5 according to beta release note: [Resolved in Xcode 9 beta 5 – IDE](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9_beta_5/Release_Notes_for_Xcode_9_beta_5.pdf)

Here is how:

1. Press and hold <kbd>⌘</kbd> (command) button in keyboard and move/hover mouse cursor on any (start or end) braces. It will automatically highlight, block area.
2. Keep (hold) <kbd>⌘</kbd> (command) button in pressed condition and click on highlighted area. It will enable quick menu popover window with **`Fold`** option.
3. Select **`Fold`** from menu list. It will fold your code and shows 3 dots, folding/covering entire block.
4. Now, to again unfold your code block, release <kbd>⌘</kbd> (command) button and click on 3 dots folding a block.

**For easy understanding, look at this snapshot:**

[image]

It's all keyboard short cuts are also working.

```
Fold                        ⌥ ⌘ ←      option + command + left arrow
Unfold                      ⌥ ⌘ →      option + command + right arrow
Unfold All                  ⌥ U        option + U
Fold Methods/Functions      ⌥ ⌘ ↑      option + command + up arrow
Unfold Methods/Functions    ⌥ ⌘ ↓      option + command + down arrow
```

Here is ref snapshot:

[image]

Comment: But the code folding ribbon is missing in Xcode 9 and even in the Version 9.0.1 (9A1004) release - which makes code-folding virtually unusable for me. I never realized how much I use that ribbon until it is gone. I can't actually believe that they took such a useful tool out of Xcode. I am hoping this is just temporary.

Comment: Same situation in Xcode 9.1 beta 2 also. Apple may not revert/back with actual code folding ribbon.

Comment: I can't believe that would be true. I fold/unfold large blocks of codes within functions all of the time, and the old ribbon was perfect. Now, in Xcode 9 - 1) can't find a way to do this in functions and 2) even if we could, everything takes so many more steps now. I can't even fold two blocks and try to remove the space between them because it ends up deleting one of the blocks! The worst editing experience I can imagine. I can't believe that *some* higher-up Apple employee developer wouldn't have anything to say about this...

Answer (score 0):

Run the following with your cursor on the curly braces:

To fold: **⌥ ⌘ ←**  Option + Command + Left Arrow

To unfold: **⌥ ⌘ →**  Option + Command + Right Arrow